# Frame Layout fades away when opening navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am developing a mobile app in android for listing the most recent news. I have implemented the navigation drawer to select the categories. For this I have used fragments and frame layout. When I open navigation drawer the layout in the background seem to fade away or the screen brightennes gets darker.

Is there a way to make me possible to open the navigation drawer without fading away the frame layout.(in xml file or programatically)

I cant post pictures ( because of my low reputation number) but if it helps below is my xml file.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/time_al_blue"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Never tried this method myself but I think using _Color.TRANSPARENT_ for _DrawerLayout.setScrimColor(int)_ should have desired effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That shadow is called the [**scrim color**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setScrimColor%28int%29).

You want to make it transparent, so your content is not obscured, i.e.

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that it would be best if you use Sliding Menu  from [Jeremy Feinstein](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Here you can find an [implementation of his library](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example)  and if you like this solution you can use it to replace navigation drawer.